How do I solve Schroedinger equation for Hydrogen atom with 3D delta-function potential?
First of all, this is not a homework question. The point of this exercise is to understand how Hydrogen atom, Positronium and ultimately strong bound states behave when Darwin-type potential is added to Coulomb potential. In all textbooks this is treated as perturbation theory problem (in the context of fine structure), but that fails even when perturbation theory converges, let alone when it doesn't.
For example $U^{91+}$ atom has effective $\alpha=92/137\approx 2/3$ (so perturbation expansion should in principle converge), and the first order correction for Darwin potential is of order $\alpha^4$ which is about half the binding energy, about an order of magnitude larger than the actual value. One can calculate higher order contributions, but it becomes impossible to do it beyond 4th order, and even that doesn't really produce results (because many more terms are needed to get the desired accuracy).
In this particular example one can use Dirac equation to get the energy, but that includes both relativistic corrections, spin-orbit corrections, Darwin corrections and it's impossible to separate the contributions. When $\alpha>1$, Dirac equation fails (formula for energies returns complex numbers) and that approach fails completely (also, perturbation expansion seems to diverge).
So the idea is to first solve the Schroedinger equation for non-relativistic Hydrogen atom with delta-function perturbation analytically and get an understanding how that delta-function affects energies and wave functions when the interaction is strong, and hence separate effects of Darwin term from relativistic effects. This would in principle also answer (or if not answer, then shed some light on) the question why does the Dirac equation fail when $\alpha>1$? For $l=0$ solutions spin-orbit interaction doesn't contribute, so is the Darwin term or the relativistic corrections that that cause the problem?
Therefore, I'm trying to solve the Schroedinger equation for Hydrogen atom with delta-function perturbation (essentially Darwin potential)
$$
\frac{p^2}{2m}\psi -\frac{\alpha}{r}\psi +b \delta^3(\vec{r})\psi=E\psi
$$
where parameter $b$ is not necessarily small. If I express the 3D delta function in terms of 1D delta function
$$
\delta^3(\vec{r})=\frac{\delta(r)}{2\pi r^2}
$$
I get
$$
\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial r^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r} +\frac{2m\alpha}{r}-\frac{m b/\pi\delta(r) +l(l+1)}{r^2}\psi +2mE\psi=0
$$
which is exactly the same as unperturbed Hydrogen atom for $r>0$, so the only difference is at $r=0$. From perturbation theory I know that the effect of $\delta$-function cannot be neglected, and is non-zero only for $l=0$ states (since unperturbed wave function vanishes for $l>0$ states at origin), but I'm uncertain how to solve this equation?
For $s$ orbital solutions, effects of the $\delta$-function would presumably show as some sort of boundary condition at $r=0$? Since the added potential is infinitely positive at $r=0$, presumably wave function should vanish at $r=0$? Also, presumably there's some sort of condition on it's derivative?
Sounds like I'm missing something here, but I don't know what.

What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

I'm stuck at boundary conditions. Your typical textbook writes the wave function as product of exponential term times some function $f$ and then requires that the power series expansion of $f$ terminates after a finite number of terms (yielding Laguerre polynomials), and that yields the usual expression for energy (nowhere is wave function or it's derivative mentioned at $r=0$). So how does one proceed when there's a delta function at r=0?

The effect of s 3d delta function is encoded in the "scattering length" boundary condition at the origin $r=0$. There is a discussion starting about on page 375 of our book. A draft copy is at https://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/bookmaster.pdf   The three d delta is discussed in Excercise 8.6 and 8.7

There are two main questions here: a technical question about the "exact" eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian
$$
H=-\frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^D\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i^2}+U(\vec{r})+\lambda\delta(\vec{r})\equiv H^{(0)}+\lambda\delta(\vec{r}) \ ,
$$
and a conceptual one about incorporating higher relativistic corrections beyond first-order perturbation theory. The TL;DR version of the answer is: the eigenvalue problem of this $H$ is ill-defined and there are no well-behaving bound state eigenvalues (with a possible loophole mentioned in Addendum 4), but this is not a problem from a physical point of view because solving the Schrodinger equation with a Darwin-like effective potential would not be suitable to account for higher relativistic effects anyway. Let us discuss both issues.
Eigenvalue problem with a repulsive Dirac delta term
Consider the above Hamiltonian in $D$ spatial dimensions with an arbitrary potential $U(\vec{r})$ ($U(\vec{r})=-Z\alpha/r$ for the Coulomb potential in $D=3$), and $\lambda>0$ (for most $U(\vec{r})$, $H$ would not be bounded from below with $\lambda<0$, $D\geq2$,  as shown here).
To get a formal solution of $H\psi(\vec{r})=E\psi(\vec{r})$, we expand $\psi(\vec{r})$ in the basis of the eigenfunctions of $H^{(0)}$ (the usual Coulomb eigenfunctions for $U(\vec{r})=-Z\alpha/r$):
$$
\psi(\vec{r})=\sum_k a_k\phi_k(\vec{r}) \ . 
$$
Inserting this into $H\psi(\vec{r})=E\psi(\vec{r})$ and using $H^{(0)}\phi_k(\vec{r})=\varepsilon_k\phi_k(\vec{r})$ as well as the properties of the delta function lead to
$$
\psi(\vec{r})=\sum_k\left(\lambda\psi(0)\frac{\phi_k^*(0)}{E-\varepsilon_k}\right)\phi_k(\vec{r})=\lambda\psi(0){\cal{G}}(\vec{r},0;E) \ ,
\tag{$\star$}
$$
where ${\cal{G}}(\vec{r},\vec{r}{}';E)$ is the Green's function of $H^{(0)}$:
$$
{\cal{G}}(\vec{r},\vec{r}{}';E)=\sum_k\frac{\phi_k(\vec{r})\phi^*_k(\vec{r}{}')}{E-\varepsilon_k}=\left\langle \vec{r}\left |\frac{1}{E-H^{(0)}}\right|\vec{r}{}'\right\rangle \ .
$$
Note that I assumed $E$ to be a bound state energy distinct from any $\varepsilon_k$, so no need for any $i0^+$ prescription. An alternative way to derive $(\star)$ is to start from the homogeneous Lippmann-Schwinger equation for bound states (see e.g. notes 38 of Littlejohn):
$$
\psi(\vec{r})=\int\mathrm{d}^Dr \, {\cal{G}}(\vec{r},\vec{r}{}';E)W(\vec{r}{}')\psi(\vec{r}{}') \ ,
$$
and just substitute $W(\vec{r})=\lambda\delta(\vec{r})$. Setting $\vec{r}=0$ in $(\star)$ gives an algebraic equation from which the exact eigenvalues could in principle be found, since everything there except for $E$ is known by construction:
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}={\cal{G}}(0,0;E) \ .
\tag{$\star\star$}
$$
Once a specific $E_i$ is found, it can be substituted back into $(\star)$, and $\psi_i(0)$ can be found from the requirement $\langle\psi_i|\psi_i\rangle=1$; the eigenfunction belonging to that $E_i$ is then completely determined. To make connection with perturbation theory, we can rearrange $(\star\star)$ as
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda}=\frac{|\phi_i(0)|^2}{E_i-\varepsilon_i}+\sum_{k\neq i}\frac{|\phi_k(0)|^2}{E_i-\varepsilon_k} \ ,
$$
$$
E_i=\varepsilon_i+\lambda|\phi_i(0)|^2+\lambda(E_i-\varepsilon_i)\sum_{k\neq i}\frac{|\phi_k(0)|^2}{E_i-\varepsilon_k}
$$
for some $\varepsilon_i$ that is assumed to be close to $E_i$, and for small $\lambda$ (and assuming no degeneracies), we can start iterating this equation to get
$$
E_i=\varepsilon_i+\lambda|\phi_i(0)|^2+\lambda^2|\phi_i(0)|^2\sum_{k\neq i}\frac{|\phi_k(0)|^2}{\varepsilon_i-\varepsilon_k}+{\cal{O}}(\lambda^3) \ .
$$
These are just the standard Rayleigh-Schrodinger perturbation corrections.
In Am. J. Phys. 43 301 (1975), Atkinson and Crater used the above formalism to find exact eigenvalues for various $U(\vec{r})$ in $D=1$; however, they also showed that the question becomes ill-defined for $D\geq2$, as the Green's function becomes divergent in the $\vec{r}\rightarrow0$ limit. A pedestrian way to see this for the Coulomb potential is to write
$$
{\cal{G}}(0,0;E)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\phi_{n00}(0)|^2}{E-\varepsilon_n}+\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}\varepsilon\frac{|\phi_{\varepsilon 00}(0)|^2}{E-\varepsilon}
$$
for the bound and scattering part of the hydrogenic spectrum (only $S$ states contribute, so $l=m_l=0$), and use
$$
|\phi_{n00}(0)|^2=\frac{m(Z\alpha)^3}{\pi n^3} \ , 
$$
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|\phi_{\varepsilon 00}(0)|^2
&=\frac{pm}{2\pi^2}\left|\Gamma\left(1+i\frac{m Z\alpha}{p}\right)\right|^2\exp\left(\frac{\pi m Z\alpha}{p}\right)  \\
&=
\frac{m^2Z\alpha}{\pi}
\left[
1-\exp\left(-2\pi\frac{mZ\alpha}{p}\right)
\right]^{-1}
 \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $p=\sqrt{2m \varepsilon}$ and $\Gamma(z)$ is the Euler gamma function. This shows $|\phi_{n 00}(0)|^2\sim n^{-3}$ and $|\phi_{\varepsilon 00}(0)|^2\sim\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ for large $\varepsilon$. The sum over bound states converges, but the integral over scattering states is divergent, and no meaningful eigenvalues can be extracted from $(\star\star)$.
Alternatively, one can show that ${\cal{G}}(\vec{r},0,E)\sim1/r$ for small $r$ (see e.g. Sec. 4.3.1-4.3.2 of Jentschura & Adkins), which by $(\star)$ means $\psi(\vec{r})\sim1/r$ for small $r$. But then $\delta(\vec{r})\psi(\vec{r})$ is ill-defined in the Schrodinger equation, and we ran into a contradiction.
Atkinson and Crater tried to regularize the problem by treating the delta function term as the limit of a constant potential barrier, and found that the effect of the potential well vanishes when the delta function limit is performed. These results, however, contradict the ones obtained by first-order perturbation theory, and highlight that the delta function term is extremely sensitive to the method of regularization (see also Addendum 2).
Higher relativistic corrections
The fact that the eigenvalue problem of $H$ is not well-defined is at first rather uncomfortable: there are no well-defined exact eigenvalues, and all perturbative energy corrections beyond first-order are divergent (this follows from the large $\varepsilon$ asymptotics of $|\phi_{\varepsilon 00}(0)|^2$, just like in the exact case; see also Schwartz, Ann. Phys. 6 2 156 (1959), where the first-order wave function is analytically constructed for the delta potential, making the divergence of the second-order energy explicit). But at the same time, the first-order correction is finite, and gives a correct and important contribution to the fine structure of hydrogen.
The punchline is that spin-orbit and Darwin-like interactions cannot be used universally, because they are not "fundamental" as e.g. a Coulomb interaction is; they are only effective potentials specifically constructed to imitate the results of a more complete theory (in this case, the Dirac theory) up to some perturbative order. Higher-order effects are incorporated by constructing higher-order effective operators and using those in perturbation theory as well, not by trying to insert the same low-order approximation in some high-order perturbative (or all-order "exact") correction. To make this clearer, consider the ground state energy of the Dirac Hamiltonian:
$$
\begin{aligned}
{\cal{E}}
&=
m\sqrt{1-(Z\alpha)^2} \\
&=
m-\frac{1}{2}m(Z\alpha)^2-\frac{1}{8}m(Z\alpha)^4-\frac{1}{16}m(Z\alpha)^6+{\cal{O}}(m(Z\alpha)^8) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
If instead of the exact energy, we just wanted to find the energy to say $(Z\alpha)^6$ accuracy, then we should construct the appropriate effective operators to that order in the Foldy-Wouthuysen framework:
$$
{\cal{H}}_\text{eff}=m+{\cal{H}}^{(2)}+{\cal{H}}^{(4)}+{\cal{H}}^{(6)} \ ,
$$
where
$$
{\cal{H}}^{(2)}=\frac{1}{2m}\vec{p}^2+U \ ,
$$
$$
{\cal{H}}^{(4)}=-\frac{1}{8m^3}\vec{p}{}^4+\frac{1}{8m^2}\nabla^2U+\frac{1}{2m^2}\vec{S}\cdot(\nabla U\times\vec{p}) \ ,
$$
$$
{\cal{H}}^{(6)}=\frac{1}{16m^5}\vec{p}{}^6-\frac{3}{64m^4}\{\vec{p}{}^2,\nabla^2U+4\vec{S}\cdot(\nabla U\times\vec{p})\}+\frac{5}{128m^4}[\vec{p}{}^2,[\vec{p}{}^2,U]]+\frac{(\nabla U)^2}{8m^3} \ .
$$
Here, ${\cal{H}}^{(2)}$ is the usual nonrelativistic Hamiltonian, and ${\cal{H}}^{(4)}$ contains the mass-velocity, Darwin, and spin-orbit terms; ${\cal{H}}^{(6)}$ is much more complicated with no simple interpretation.
The $(Z\alpha)^2$ and $(Z\alpha)^4$ contributions to the energy are simply given by first-order perturbation theory with the non-relativistic ground state:
$$
E^{(2)}=\langle\phi_0|{\cal{H}}^{(2)}|\phi_0\rangle=-\frac{1}{2}m(Z\alpha)^2 \ ,
$$
$$
E^{(4)}=\langle\phi_0|{\cal{H}}^{(4)}|\phi_0\rangle=-\frac{1}{8}m(Z\alpha)^4 \ .
$$
However, to get the complete $(Z\alpha)^6$ contribution, a second-order correction must be calculated with ${\cal{H}}^{(4)}$ as well, since ${\cal{H}}^{(4)}\sim(Z\alpha)^4$ and $\varepsilon_0-\varepsilon_k\sim(Z\alpha)^2$:
$$
E^{(6)}=\langle\phi_0|{\cal{H}}^{(6)}|\phi_0\rangle+\sum_{k\neq0}\frac{\langle\phi_0|{\cal{H}}^{(4)}|\phi_k\rangle\langle\phi_k|{\cal{H}}^{(4)}|\phi_0\rangle}{\varepsilon_0-\varepsilon_k} \ .
$$
We saw on the example of the Darwin interaction that the second term is divergent; it turns out that the first term is divergent too, but when added together in an appropriate regularization (like $U_\lambda(\vec{r})= U(\vec{r})(1-\exp(-\lambda r))$ with $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$ in the end),  their sum ends up finite and gives the correct $E^{(6)}=-m(Z\alpha)^6/16$ value (Pachucki, Phys. Rev. A 56 297 (1997)).
Similar divergences and cancellations are expected in higher $Z\alpha$ orders as well. When you tried to solve the Schrodinger equation for the Darwin term (without any higher-order operators) you used an effective interaction beyond its range of applicability, and no meaningful, consistent result can be expected from this.
For high $Z$ (like $Z=92$ in your example) the convergence of the $Z\alpha$ expansion is very slow, and there is no really better choice than to use the full solution of the Dirac equation. Of course, in that solution you cannot separate the effect of mass-velocity, Darwin and spin-orbit terms anymore, but this is natural, as such a separation is only possible in leading order: in higher orders, these effects combine in very complicated ways as already shown by ${\cal{H}}^{(6)}$.
(About the possible failure of the Dirac equation when $Z\alpha>1$: currently we do not even know what is beyond $Z=118$, so no one has any idea what to expect from $Z>137$. But note that solving the Dirac equation with not a point-like but a finite nucleus pushes the value of critical $Z$ quite higher.)
Addendum 1: analytic derivation of the first-order wave function
Here I derive the first-order wave function for the hydrogenic ground state in a Dirac delta perturbation to complement the result of Schwartz (Eq. (15) in his paper; he only gave the result without derivation). The Hamiltonian in atomic units reads
$$
H=-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r}+\lambda\delta(\vec{r})\equiv H^{(0)}+W \ ,
$$
and the zeroth-order wave function and zeroth- and first-order energy is
$$
\phi^{(0)}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\exp(-r) \ \ , \ \ E^{(0)}=-\frac{1}{2} \ \ , \ \ E^{(1)}=\langle\phi^{(0)}|W|\phi^{(0)}\rangle=\frac{\lambda}{\pi} \  .
$$
If
$$
H^{(0)}\psi^{(1)}+W\psi^{(0)}=E^{(0)}\psi^{(1)}+E^{(1)}\psi^{(0)}
$$
is solved for the first-order wave function $\psi^{(1)}$, then the second-order energy can be readily computed as
$$
E^{(2)}=\langle\phi^{(0)}|W|\phi^{(1)}\rangle-E^{(1)}\langle\phi^{(0)}|\phi^{(1)}\rangle \ .
\tag{$\star\star\star$}
$$
Note that I am not using intermediate normalization, so in general $\langle\phi^{(0)}|\phi^{(1)}\rangle\neq0$.
The equation to solve is
$$
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\nabla^2-\frac{1}{r}+\frac{1}{2}\right]\phi^{(1)}(\vec{r})+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\left[2\pi\delta(\vec{r})-2\right]\exp(-r)=0 \ .
$$
Since $\phi^{(1)}$ must have $S$ symmetry, we may substitute the Ansatz
$$
\phi^{(1)}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\chi(r)\exp(-r) \ .
$$
After carrying out the differentiations, we get
$$
\nabla^2\chi(r)-2\chi'(r)=4\pi\delta(\vec{r})-4 \ ,
$$
where $'$ means differentation with respect to $r$, and actually
$$
\nabla^2\chi(r)=\chi''(r)+\frac{2}{r}\chi'(r) \ .
$$
Substituting $\chi(r)=\zeta(r)-1/r$ and using
$$
\nabla^2\frac{1}{r}=-4\pi\delta(\vec{r}) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 
\nabla^2\chi(r)=\zeta''(r)+\frac{2}{r}\zeta'(r)+4\pi\delta(\vec{r})
$$
leads to
$$
\zeta''(r)+\frac{2}{r}\zeta'(r)-2\zeta'(r)-\frac{2}{r^2}+4=0 \ .
$$
One more substitution $\Omega(r)=\zeta'(r)$ yields the first-order differential equation
$$
\Omega'(r)+\frac{2}{r}\Omega(r)-2\Omega(r)-\frac{2}{r^2}+4=0 \ ,
$$
which is solved by
$$
\Omega(r)=c'\frac{\exp(2r)}{r^2}+\frac{2}{r}+2 \ .
$$
We must set $c'=0$, otherwise the solution is not normalizable. Then
$$
\zeta(r)=2r+2\ln(r)+c \ ,
$$
and
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi^{(1)}(\vec{r})
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\left[2r+2\ln(r)-\frac{1}{r}+c\right]\exp(-r) \\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\left[2r+2\ln(r)-\frac{1}{r}\right]\exp(-r)+\tilde{c}\phi^{(0)}(\vec{r})
 \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
There is an arbitrary integration constant in the solution that gives a component to $\phi^{(1)}$ which is proportional to $\phi^{(0)}$. You could fix this constant by e.g. requiring the intermediate normalization $\langle\phi^{(0)}|\phi^{(1)}\rangle=0$; however, by inspecting $(\star\star\star)$, it is easy to see that $E^{(2)}$ is independent of this constant, so I just set $c=0$:
$$
\phi^{(1)}(\vec{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\frac{\lambda}{\pi}\left[2r+2\ln(r)-\frac{1}{r}\right]\exp(-r) \ .
$$
This corresponds to Eq. (15) of Schwartz. Now you can see that $\psi(\vec{r})\sim1/r$ for small $r$ as claimed earlier, and therefore $E^{(2)}$ is divergent when you try to compute it with $(\star\star\star)$.
Actually, the first-order wave function also determines the third-order energy as a consequence of the $2n+1$ theorem of Wigner. If we choose $\phi^{(1)}$ to satisfy the intermediate normalization (by setting $c=2\ln(2)+2\gamma-5$, where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant), then
$$
E^{(3)}=\langle\phi^{(1)}|W|\phi^{(1)}\rangle-E^{(1)}\langle\phi^{(1)}|\phi^{(1)}\rangle \ ,
$$
and it is immediately seen, that this, too, is divergent.
Addendum 2: numerical results
As mentioned previously, Atkinson and Crater tried to make the "Coulomb+delta" eigenvalue problem well-defined by regularizing the delta function. They treated it as the limit of a constant potential barrier, and found its effect to be vanishing when the limit is taken, thereby recovering the hydrogenic ground state. Here, I numerically confirm this result in two different ways.
Approach 1: variational optimization
Since $H$ is bounded from below for $\lambda>0$, we have by the variational theorem
$$
{\cal{E}}_\text{trial}=\langle\phi_\text{trial}|H|\phi_\text{trial}\rangle\geq E
$$
for any trial function, where $E$ is the exact ground state energy. We can then try converging to $E$ by minimizing the expectation value. The trial function is parametrized as the ${\cal{N}}$-term linear combination
$$
\phi_\text{trial}(\vec{r})=\sum_{\mu=1}^{\cal{N}}c_\mu\chi_\mu(\vec{r}) \ ,
$$
where the $S$ symmetry basis functions are simple normalized Gaussians:
$$
\chi_\mu(\vec{r})=\left(\frac{2\alpha_\mu}{\pi}\right)^{3/4}\exp(-\alpha_\mu r^2)
$$
with the adjustable parameter $\alpha_\mu>0$. The Schrodinger equation then becomes a generalized matrix eigenvalue equation:
$$
\boldsymbol{Hc}=E\boldsymbol{Sc} \ ,
$$
where $H_{\mu\nu}=\langle\chi_\mu|H|\chi_\nu\rangle$, $S_{\mu\nu}=\langle\chi_\mu|\chi_\nu\rangle$ can be calculated analytically:
$$
S_{\mu\nu}=\left(\frac{4\alpha_\mu\alpha_\nu}{(\alpha_\mu+\alpha_\nu)^2}\right)^{3/4} \ ,
$$
$$
H_{\mu\nu}=\left[3\frac{\alpha_\mu\alpha_\nu}{\alpha_\mu+\alpha_\nu}-2\sqrt{\frac{\alpha_\mu+\alpha_\nu}{\pi}}+\lambda\left(\frac{\alpha_\mu+\alpha_\nu}{\pi}\right)^{3/2}\right]S_{\mu\nu} \ ,
$$
the three terms corresponding to the kinetic energy, Coulomb attraction and delta interaction.
Due to my job, I have access to a very flexible variational solver, where basically everything was already implemented; I only had to build the very simple matrix elements of the delta interaction. In the calculation, the values of $c_\mu$ are determined by repeatedly solving the matrix eigenvalue equation, while the Gaussian parameters $\alpha_\mu$ are refined in a stochastic optimization cycle. I performed this variational calculation for more and more basis functions, and the ground state energy is seen to converge to the pure hydrogenic limit.
\begin{array}{r|ccccc}
 {\cal{N}} & E \, (\lambda=0.0) & E \, (\lambda=0.01) & E \, (\lambda=0.1) & E \, (\lambda=1.0) & E \, (\lambda=10.0) \\ 
\hline
  1 & -0.424413182 & -0.423651782 & -0.417062450 & -0.368511994 &  -0.226365895 \\
  5 & -0.499809832 & -0.498997446 & -0.499277868 & -0.499277712 & -0.499277627 \\
 10 & -0.499999161 & -0.499997094 & -0.499992511 & -0.499997327 & -0.499997229 \\
 20 & -0.499999986 & -0.499999655 & -0.499999241 & -0.499999424 & -0.499999071
\end{array}
For $\lambda<0$, the calculation of course quickly fails, since $H$ is not bounded from below.
Just to be sure, I checked the method for another perturbing potential, $W=\lambda r$. For small $\lambda$, the numerical variational results were in very good agreement with the known analytical PT corrections for this linear potential:
$$
{\cal{E}}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}\lambda-\frac{3}{2}\lambda^2+\frac{27}{4}\lambda^3+{\cal{O}(\lambda^4)} \ .
$$
For example, for $\lambda=0.01$, I found $E_\text{var}=-0.485144$ and $E_\text{PT}=-0.485143$.
Approach 2: Dirac delta as a limit of Gaussians
When writing $\psi(\vec{r})=\chi(r)/(\sqrt{4\pi}r)$, the radial Schrodinger equation reads
$$
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}-\frac{1}{r}+\lambda\frac{\delta(r)}{4\pi r^2}\right]\chi(r)=E\chi(r) \ .
$$
I regularized the radial delta function  as
$$
\delta_\xi(r)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}\xi}\exp(-r^2/\xi^2) \ ,
$$
and calculated the lowest eigenvalue with the NDEigensystem routine of Mathematica for increasingly smaller values of $\xi$. The table shows once again that the ground state energy converges to that of a simple hydrogen as $\xi\rightarrow0^+$.
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
 \xi & E \, (\lambda=0.1) & E \, (\lambda=1.0) & E \, (\lambda=10.0) \\ 
\hline
 10^{-1} & -0.488128 & -0.447406 & -0.397968 \\
 10^{-2} & -0.493161 & -0.484291 & -0.476065 \\
 10^{-3} & -0.498289 & -0.497295 & -0.496416 \\
 10^{-4} & -0.499724 & -0.499631 & -0.499550 \\
 10^{-5} & -0.499965 & -0.499957 & -0.499950
\end{array}
It seems the delta function is "lost" within the Coulomb singularity. Note that this is not a numerical artifact, if we placed the Dirac delta somewhere else (by $\delta(r)\rightarrow\delta(r-r_0)$), the ground state energy would actually change. For $r_0=1$ and $\lambda=10.0$, I found that the energy converged to $E\approx-0.265$.
Addendum 3: final remarks
So, we have an eigenvalue problem that produces severe divergences when attacked with Green's function techniques or perturbation theory, but immediately collapses to a trivial, "delta funcion-less" problem when treated variationally, or with a regularization; results from this latter, trivial problem, however, are in contradiction with the observation that the finite first-order energy correction gives correct values. Actually, just after doing the numerical work, I found another paper (Velenik, Zivkovic, de Jeu, Murrell, Mol. Phys. 18 5 693 (1970)) which explicitly shows that variational calculations with the "Coulomb+delta" potential just collapse to the hydrogenic ground state and that beyond-leading-order perturbation theory becomes useless (see also Blinder, Phys. Rev. A 18 853 (1978) and Blinder, Theor. Chim. Acta 53 159 (1979)).
This eigenvalue problem is ill-posed, and just shows that one should not use low-order effective operators beyond first-order PT. Delta function interactions appear in many areas of QM (fine- and hyperfine structure of atoms, the annihilation contribution to the hyperfine splitting of positronium, vacuum polarization and other effects in QED, etc.) as low-energy approximations to some more fundamental process. There is no reason to believe that these interactions could be consistently used beyond their range of applicability. The fact that the second-order energy correction with a delta function perturbation is divergent has been known at least since the 1950's. In the context of higher-order hyperfine effects, people tried to smooth out the delta potential, so that the nucleus is not treated anymore as a point-like magnetic dipole, while for the Darwin term (and many other similar terms in bound state QED), the divergences are cancelled by higher-order effective operators in the Foldy-Wouthuysen formalism. There is nothing more to gain from low-order approximate interactions.
Addendum 4: self-adjoint extensions
It just came to my attention that while the original eigenvalue problem of $H$ with the usual boundary conditions is ill-posed, there exists a modification of the problem via the self-adjoint extension of $H$, which is well defined, and could, in principle, provide well-behaving eigenvalues (see e.g. here and here). This is a very interesting mathematical topic on its own right, but from a physical point of view, I doubt the eigenvalues would carry useful information beyond their first-order contributions. The sources of trouble in the original, ill-defined problem are the missing finer physical effects. Also, I would be very surprised if the eigenvalues of the modified, well-defined problem turned out to be different from the "delta-less" eigenvalues found with the variational or regularization approach.
Addendum 5: addressing the comments
1. Normalizability of the wave functon with continuum components
There are quite a few questions/doubts in the comments about the role of continuum states in perturbation theory, the first being about the normalizability of a wave function that has both discrete and continuum state contributions in some basis.
Let $H^{(0)}$ have both discrete and continuum eigenstates ($\{|\phi^{(0)}_k\rangle\}$ and $\{|\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)\rangle\}$ for some continuous $\alpha$ over some domain $\Omega$). These states are orthonormal in the following sense:
$$
\langle\phi^{(0)}_k|\phi^{(0)}_l\rangle=\delta_{kl} \ \ , \ \ \langle\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)|\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)\rangle=\delta(\alpha-\alpha') \ \ , \ \
\langle\phi^{(0)}_k|\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)\rangle=0 \ ,
$$
and complete, meaning that an arbitrary state of the function space can be expanded in them as
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\sum_kc_k|\phi^{(0)}_k\rangle+\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}\alpha \, c(\alpha)|\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)\rangle \ ,
$$
with components $c_k=\langle\phi^{(0)}_k|\Psi\rangle$, $c(\alpha)=\langle\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)|\Psi\rangle$.
Nothing prevents this state from being normalizable; for example, $\langle\Psi|\Psi\rangle=1$ if
$$
\sum_k|c_k|^2+\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}\alpha \, |c(\alpha)|^2=1 \ ,
$$
as follows from the orthogonality relations. For example, $|\Psi\rangle$ could be a bound eigenstate of some other Hamiltonian $H=H^{(0)}+W$. In this basis, the identity operator has the resolution
$$
I=\sum_k|\phi^{(0)}_k\rangle\langle\phi^{(0)}_k|+\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}\alpha \, |\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)\rangle\langle\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)| \ ,
$$
since this maps every state onto itself: $I|\Psi\rangle=|\Psi\rangle$. Note that continuum states are normalized to delta function, but this is not a problem since they always appear behind an integral over $\alpha$.
The first-order wave function and the second-order energy corrections formally read
$$
|\phi^{(1)}_n\rangle=\frac{P_n^\perp}{E^{(0)}_n-H^{(0)}}W|\phi^{(0)}_n\rangle \ ,
$$
$$
E^{(2)}_n=\langle\phi^{(0)}_n|W|\phi^{(1)}_n\rangle=\left\langle\phi^{(0)}_n\left|W\frac{P_n^\perp}{E^{(0)}_n-H^{(0)}}W\right|\phi^{(0)}_n\right\rangle \ ,
$$
where $P_n^\perp=I-|\phi^{(0)}_n\rangle\langle\phi^{(0)}_n|$ is a projector onto the subspace orthogonal to $|\phi^{(0)}_n\rangle$ (we assumed no degeneracies), and we used intermediate normalization (so that $P_n^\perp|\phi^{(1)}_n\rangle=|\phi^{(1)}_n\rangle$). Substituting the above resolution of identity gives
$$
|\phi^{(1)}_n\rangle=\sum_{k\neq n}\frac{\langle \phi_k^{(0)}|W|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle}{E^{(0)}_n-E^{(0)}_k}|\phi_k^{(0)}\rangle+\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}\alpha \, \frac{\langle \phi^{(0)}(\alpha)|W|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle}{E^{(0)}_n-E^{(0)}(\alpha)}|\phi(\alpha)^{(0)}\rangle \ ,
$$
$$
E^{(2)}_n=\sum_{k\neq n}\frac{|\langle \phi_k^{(0)}|W|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle|^2}{E^{(0)}_n-E^{(0)}_k}+\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}\alpha \, \frac{|\langle \phi^{(0)}(\alpha)|W|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle|^2}{E^{(0)}_n-E^{(0)}(\alpha)} \ .
$$
These continuum contributions tend to be discussed in textbooks (see e.g. Landau & Lifshitz III or Chapters 31 and 33 of Schiff).
Additionally, think of how the basis of plane waves is continuous in the infinite box limit, but you can still construct localized, normalizable wave packets (e.g. Gaussians) with them.
It is easy to check that the analytical first-order wave function I wrote down in Addendum 1 for the delta perturbation has a non-zero overlap with the hydrogenic continuum states, therefore it has continuum components. Just pick some value for $\varepsilon$, and compute the integral $\langle\phi^{(0)}_{\varepsilon00}|\phi^{(1)}\rangle$ numerically.
2. Box normalization of scattering states and the continuum limit
You seem to claim that continuum contributions can be neglected based on the following argument: you first put the system in a box, so that scattering states (when normalized as $\langle\psi_\alpha|\psi_{\alpha'}\rangle=\delta_{\alpha\alpha'}$) scale as $|\psi_{\alpha}\rangle\sim1/\sqrt{L}$, and then $|\psi_\alpha\rangle\langle\psi_\alpha|\sim1/L$ vanishes in the limit $L\rightarrow\infty$. The flaw in this argument is that this factor of $1/L$ is absorbed in the summation over $\alpha$ as it turns into an integration in the continuum limit.
To see this, consider first plane waves in 1D. In case of a finite box, we have
$$
\phi_n(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}\exp(ik_nx) \ \ , \ \ k_n=\frac{2\pi n}{L} \ ,
$$
with orthonormality and completeness relations
$$
\int_{-\frac{L}{2}}^{+\frac{L}{2}}\mathrm{d}x \, \phi^*_n(x)\phi_m(x)=\delta_{mn} \ \ , \ \ 
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi_n(x)\phi^*_n(x')=\delta(x-x') \ .
$$
In the infinite space limit, we should have
$$
\phi(x;k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(ikx) \ ,
$$
with
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}x \, \phi^*(x;k)\phi(x;k')=\delta(k-k') \ \ , \ \ 
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}k \, \phi(x;k)\phi^*(x';k)=\delta(x-x') \ .
$$
To actually get this second relation (and not identically zero!), we must absorb the $1/L$ in the summation over $n$ as we pass to the continuum limit:
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi_n(x)\phi^*_n(x')=
\underbrace{\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2\pi}{L}}_{\rightarrow\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}k}\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\pi}\exp(ik_n(x-x'))}_{\rightarrow\phi(x;k)\phi^*(x';k)}
\rightarrow\delta(x-x') \ .
$$
This is exactly what happens in the PT formulae too. In a box, the "original" continuum states have the property
$$
\langle\phi^{(0)}_\alpha|\phi^{(0)}_{\alpha'}\rangle=\delta_{\alpha\alpha'}\frac{L}{\kappa} \ ,
$$
where $\kappa>0$ is some uninteresting numerical factor. Of course, in the finite box treatment, you can re-normalize these states as
$$
|\psi^{(0)}_\alpha\rangle=\sqrt{\frac{\kappa}{L}}|\phi^{(0)}_{\alpha}\rangle \ \ , \ \ \langle\psi^{(0)}_\alpha|\psi^{(0)}_{\alpha'}\rangle=\delta_{\alpha\alpha'} \ ,
$$
and then you can treat everything as a sum; e.g.
$$
I=\sum_k|\phi^{(0)}_k\rangle\langle\phi^{(0)}_k|+\sum_\alpha |\psi^{(0)}_\alpha\rangle\langle\psi^{(0)}_\alpha| \ .
$$
But if you want to take the $L\rightarrow\infty$ limit, then that factor of $\kappa/L$ will be a part of the integration measure, and nothing tends to zero:
$$
\sum_\alpha\frac{|\langle\psi^{(0)}_\alpha|W|\phi^{(0)}_n\rangle|^2}{E_n^{(0)}-E_\alpha^{(0)}}=
\underbrace{\sum_\alpha\frac{\kappa}{L}}_{\rightarrow\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}\alpha}
\underbrace{\frac{|\langle\phi^{(0)}_\alpha|W|\phi^{(0)}_n\rangle|^2}{E_n^{(0)}-E_\alpha^{(0)}}}_{\rightarrow\frac{|\langle\phi^{(0)}(\alpha)|W|\phi^{(0)}_n\rangle|^2}{E_n^{(0)}-E^{(0)}(\alpha)}}
\rightarrow
\int_\Omega\mathrm{d}\alpha \, \frac{|\langle \phi^{(0)}(\alpha)|W|\phi_n^{(0)}\rangle|^2}{E^{(0)}_n-E^{(0)}(\alpha)} \ .
$$

Thank you dennismoore94 for your detailed answer. I'll check the references you quoted and see if they shed some extra light. I'm not sure I agree with your conclusions that the eigenvalue problem is not well defined; one can treat Darwin potential as a small perturbation and apply perturbation theory to it. Since matrix elements $V_{nm}\sim (n m)^{-3/2}$ are very simple, corrections can be reasonably easily evaluated. At the moment I'm up to 5th order (so to $\alpha^{12}$) and everything seems to work just fine, so it sounds to me the solution (at least in principle) must exist.

Bottom line seems to be that nobody seems to know how to solve this eigenvalue problem?

@Bob Thanks for your feedback. I don't really understand your comment about 5-th order PT. Do you also include the continuum part of the hydrogenic spectrum in the calculation? You need that, otherwise the system of unperturbed functions is not complete, and it is the continuum part that makes the PT corrections diverge.

if by "continuum part of hydrogenic spectrum" you mean Coulomb wave functions, the answer is no, I wasn't including them. As far as I can tell they are not normalizable (?) so I can see why they would cause problems. It seems reasonable to claim intuitively on ``physical'' grounds that their contribution should be smaller than contribution of bound states (which may well turn out to be nonsense)? The fact is that Darwin contribution does exist in real life, so sounds like something is wrong with the math here?

@Bob Yes, the continuum part is the integral over scattering states. They are normalized to delta function in energy, but that is fine. The continuum part is often important in PT (think of e.g. the quadratic Stark effect). In the present case, you get finite PT results only because you sum over only the discrete part of the zeroth-order spectrum. This shows that the Darwin term is not suitable for higher order PT corrections without other operators. I think you're seeing too much into the Darwin term. It is just a term in the F-W expansion of the Dirac Hamiltonian, and not much more.

@Bob I added a reference to a paper by Scwartz, where the first-order wave function is analytically calculated for the delta potential, which explicitly shows the divergence of second-order energy (he does not deal with the Darwin interaction, but with a Fermi contact interaction in the context of hyperfine structure, but mathematically, both are described by the same Dirac delta term).

Thank you @dennismoore94. I'll try to read the reference if I manage to find it. I think you are wrong, those matrix elements of Darwin potential between bound states and continuum states have to vanish; otherwise even a tiny perturbation would lead to wave function being a superposition of bound and continuum states, which just doesn't make sense physically.

And you are wrong about Darwin part being just an F-W expansion of Dirac Hamiltonian; as you yourself point out (the Schwartz article), mathematically the same potential arises from spin-spin interaction and many others, so it's important to understand it's properties.

@Bob I'm not wrong. The matrix element between a bound and a scattering $S$ state reads
$$
|\langle\phi_{n00}|\delta(\vec{r})|\phi_{\varepsilon 00}\rangle|^2=|\phi_{n 00}(0)|^2|\phi_{\varepsilon 00}(0)|^2 \ ,
$$
and this only vanishes if one of the two absolute squares above is zero, but they are generally not; I literally gave the expressions for them in my answer, but you can easily check it yourself. Perturbed states usually do get contributions from the continuum part of the zeroth-order spectrum too, nothing wrong with this (once again, quadratic Stark effect).

@Bob I added the derivation of the first-order wave function (Schwartz only gives the end result); now you can explicitly see the problem with $E^{(2)}$.

Thank you @dennismoore94. I'll study it and see if it inspires some new ideas. On your earlier statement about perturbation theory: aren't you forgetting the normalization of continuum states? $V_{nk}$ really means $\langle n|V|k\rangle / \sqrt{ \langle n|n\rangle \langle k|k\rangle}$ but for bound states normalization is always 1 so we omit the term; but for continuum states its $\delta(0)$ so divide your expression by $\sqrt{\infty}$ and it becomes zero.

Another way to think about it is to put the system into a gigantic box of size $L$ (let's say $10^{100}$ light years); continuum states become discretized and can now be normalized to $\langle k|k'\rangle=\delta_{kk'}$. That normalization constant is now proportional to $1/\sqrt{L^3}$ times some finite number. So $V_{nk}\sim 1/\sqrt{L^3}$ and when $L\to\infty$, then $V\to 0$. So continuum states don't contribute to the second order perturbation theory because transition elements between bound and continuum states are all zero.

@Bob Continuum states are already normalized; they are normalized to a delta function. Just think of a resolution of identity over a continuum spectrum characterized by $\varepsilon\in[0,\infty[$:
$$
\hat{I}=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}\varepsilon |\varepsilon\rangle\langle\varepsilon| \ ,
$$
so that
$$
\hat{I}|E\rangle=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}\varepsilon |\varepsilon\rangle\langle\varepsilon|E\rangle=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}\varepsilon |\varepsilon\rangle \delta(\varepsilon-E)=|E\rangle \ .
$$
These states are properly normalized. Dividing them by $\delta(0)$ would just make...

...them vanish, which doesn't make any sense. If this was valid, the continuum contribution would disappear for not just a Dirac delta perturbation, but for any kind of perturbation, which is simply not true! The analytic first-order wave function I just wrote down has components from both the bound and continuum part of the hydrogen spectrum (which could be checked by projecting it with hydrogenic functions).

yes @dennismoore94, that's exactly the point. If you take for example $\alpha \lambda /r^2$ perturbation, you can solve the problem exactly and expand the solution in powers of $\alpha$ (or $\lambda$) and compare with the result with what you get from perturbation theory. They match exactly with only bound-state contributions. By definition if you pick a bound state, it's going to have zero overlap with continuum states; otherwise system would be in some superposition of positive and negative energy states which doesn't make any sense. Reread the comment about putting the system into a box.

delta-function normalization means something very different, and it only makes sense under some integral (because delta-function is a distribution and hence makes sense only under integral)

@Bob Of course it only makes sense under some integral, but the continuum part of the energy correction is exactly like that:
$$
E^{(2)}\text{cont}=\int_0^\infty\mathrm{d}\varepsilon\frac{|\langle\phi{100}|W|\phi_{\varepsilon 00}\rangle|^2}{\epsilon_1-\varepsilon} \ .
$$
A question: do you accept the analytic first-order wave function I wrote down? If you do, then all you have to do is calculate its overlap with the scattering state
$$
\phi_{\varepsilon 00}\sim {_1F_1}(1+i/p,2,ipr)\exp(-ipr) \ ,
$$
where $p=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$, and $_1F_1$ is the confluent hypergeometric...

...function. Just pick a value of $\varepsilon$ and do the single radial integral numerically. You will see that it is in general non-zero, which readily shows that the continuum part of the hydrogenic spectrum does contribute to $\phi^{(1)}$, and therefore to $E^{(2)}$.

@Bob Sorry, typo, actually
$$
\phi_{\varepsilon 00}\sim{_1F_1}(1+i/p,2,2ipr)\exp(-ipr)
$$
with $p=\sqrt{2\varepsilon}$; everything else stands.

@Bob I also added numerical results that confirm the findings of Atkinson and Crater about the vanishing effect of the delta term in non-perturbative calculations. I also managed to dig up another old paper by Velenik and Zivkovic which shows the same thing, together with the complete breakdown of PT.

Thank you @dennismoore94 for going through all that effort. I really do appreciate it. To summarize: your method produces nonsense result and you conclude that therefore problem is somehow ill defined. Then the second conclusion is that PT breaks down. Seems to me you haven't considered the possibility that you're doing something wrong (that at least one of your assumptions are incorrect)?

@Bob It seems to me that you are the one who does not consider the possibility of error at all. PT is useless here, and non-perturbative methods give either divergent or completely trivial, "delta-less" results, depending on how you approach the problem. I call such a problem ill-defined; if you prefer another word, call it that. These are not my personal theories. These are well-established and proven facts from the literature, and you too would know this if you had taken the time to check the papers I cited. They are short, readable (except for the Pachucki one), and all of them can be...

...accessed via scihub. I see no point in continuing this discussion. Good luck with your studies.

I'm sorry @dennismoore94 if I have offended you; it wasn't my intention, I assure you. You have actually been a tremendous help! It just seems to me that you throw math around without thinking what the underlying physics behind it would be. For example, your idea that PT (in the first order already) would mix bound and continuum states seems so obviously wrong; how would you even normalize such a wave function? Drop your continuum states and all the divergences disappear, your original proposed solution seems to work fine (and it agrees with PT up to at least 20th order).

You also need to understand what $\delta$-function normalization means. These WFs are normalized to the volume of the space, not to unity, so you have to take that into account when using them (think of plane wave normalized to $\delta(k-k')$; if you put it in finite box of size L, the normalization becomes $L^3$, so when calculating physical matrix elements, you have to divide with $L^3$)...

@Bob I made one last attempt to convince you; see Addendum 5... Also, note that PT energies converge to the Green's function results no matter how you truncate your basis (of course both calculated in the same truncated basis), but based on this alone, you cannot assess the magnitude of the error caused by the truncation. In the case of a delta perturbation, dropping the continuum part of your basis is a singularly bad approximation because all infinities come from the continuum.
